# React with Rails - rollback in server log

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, reactjs

I have a problem. Something with the database, because before that I did not understand what with the migrations. When I run the server there is an error `log_subscriber.rb:98` from the database, no data is transmitted to the front end, although before that everything worked. There is no answer on the internet.

```
(2.5ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations"."version" FROM 
"schema_migrations" ORDER BY "schema_migrations"."version" ASC
↳ /home/vitalii/.ruby/gems/activerecord- 
5.2.2/lib/active_record/log_subscriber.rb:98

Started POST "/tasks/" for ::1 at 2019-02-17 18:09:51 +0200
   (1.2ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations"."version" FROM "schema_migrations" ORDER BY "schema_migrations"."version" ASC
  ↳ /home/vitalii/.ruby/gems/activerecord-5.2.2/lib/active_record/log_subscriber.rb:98
Processing by TasksController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"title"=>"Text", "description"=>"Text", "priority"=>"1", "active"=>true, "due_date"=>"2019-02-28", "task"=>{"title"=>"Text", "description"=>"Text", "priority"=>"1", "active"=>true, "due_date"=>"2019-02-28"}}
   (0.3ms)  BEGIN
  ↳ app/controllers/tasks_controller.rb:15
   (1.5ms)  ROLLBACK
  ↳ app/controllers/tasks_controller.rb:15
Completed 200 OK in 156ms (Views: 0.9ms | ActiveRecord: 7.1ms)
```

My Tasks Controller

```
class TasksController < ApplicationController        
  def create
    @task = Task.create(task_params)
    render json: @task
  end

  private

  def task_params
    params.require(:task).permit(:title, :description, :priority, :active, :due_date)
  end       
end
```

Comment: if this is local you can try to reset your database so Active Record will drop the database and run all migrations which will set schema_migrations table too
`rake db:reset`

Comment: In your log file I can not see any error. At the end, the server responds with 200 status code.

Comment: Also, please don't log duplicate questions it seems like you logged this one too with same description https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54732735/rails-error-active-record-logsubscriber-rb98

Comment: @zeitnot the transaction was rolled back so nothing got created in Task table

Comment: `...active_record/log_subscriber.rb:98` line is not about the error. Looks like you're trying to create invalid task. Change `@task = Task.create(task_params)` to `@task = Task.create!(task_params)` (note the bang method create!) in create action - you'll see validation error in server log

Comment: Did you add any validation to the Task model recently? The problem should be there

Answer (score 2):

Most probably your `Task` model fails silently. If there are validations, and the given input does not satisfy your validation rules, persisting will not be successful. So use `@task = Task.create!(task_params)` instruction which hash a bang instead of `@task = Task.create(task_params)`.

The most efficient way is:

```rb
def create
 @task = Task.new(task_params)
 @task.save ? head(:created) : (render json: @task.errors) 
end
```